# Symfony2 - Redirect after form processing in form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to work with dynamic forms/form types in Symfony 2. I've managed so far, but what I don't know and can't find is how to redirect after the POST_SUBMIT event.

Do I do it inside the controller or does it happen directly in the form type class? What happens atm is the page reloads, but the data in the page is not updated. Plus I would like to redirect to another page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say in the controller, after you verify the form as valid.

Comment: Check this out, is it what you are looking for? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) :

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
}
```

the `isValid()` method will return true only when a `POST` request has been performed and when the data sent is valid.
If you want to redirect after `POST` request even in the case the form is not valid, you can do this :

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action...
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('page_after_post_request'));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this before, but didn't work. Turns out my form wasn't valid.. But thanks for leading me to the solution :)